# Node crashea al no cumplir un funcion

Tags: laravel, nodejs

Los pongo en contexto, tengo un sistema en laravel que utiliza colas de envíos para enviar un mensaje a unos usuarios en otra plataforma.. y tengo el micro microservicio/api hecho en nodejs... funcional y todo...

En laravel se recolectan los mensajes, se envían a la cola, y luego la cola envía un post al microservicio/api...

Lo que deseo hacer es que cuando se envíe el mensaje, este devuelva si se envió o no... para que laravel pueda eliminarlo o no de la cola...

actualmente me devuelve el usuario y el mensaje enviado... PERO y acá esta mi problema... si por una de esas casualidades un campo no se envía (cosa que no sería problema porque lo valido con laravel antes) y/o en ese momento el servidor de envios esta desconectado lease "var wclient = sessions[0];" este el microservicio tira un error y crashea...

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
//const http = require('http');
const qs = require('querystring');
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
      var wclient = sessions[0];
      if (req.method === 'POST' && req.url === '/enviar') {
        var body = '';
        req.on('data', function(chunk) {
          body += chunk;
        });
        req.on('end', function() {
            var datos = JSON.parse(body)
            wclient.sendMessage(datos.usuario, datos.message);
              res.writeHead(200); res.end(JSON.stringify({
                "send": true,
                "send_to": datos.usuario,
                "message": datos.message
              }));
            });
        }
        else {
          res.writeHead(404);
          res.end(JSON.stringify({
            "send": false,
            "send_to": datos.usuario,
            "message": datos.message
          }));
        }
      }).listen(8081);
```

Error si se envia una petición y el servidor esta caido:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendMessage' of undefined
```

Necesitaría que si no puede conectarse y enviar el mensaje... devuelva un error (Sin crashear) para que laravel vuelva a reintentar luego..

Alguna idea?

Edit: Session:

```
interface Session extends Client {
  id?: number;
}

const sessions: Session[] = [];
```

Comment: Podrías añadir más información sobre que es la variable `sessions` ? Ya que parece que ahí es donde esta el fallo

Comment: ¿Utilizar `server.on('error', fn)` no te sirve para manejar ese error? Aún así, no entiendo por qué habría un consumo al servidor si la validación falló en el front.

Comment: Hola a ambos, ya agregue las sessions... Jonatan lo de que si una valor no se envia del front end, lo soluciono con una validación en el frontend, el problema radica en que si en ese momento no se puede conectar a la session, ahi crashéa la app... ahora reviso lo de server.on y te cuento